# I calculated the intersection of a line with a circle, got projection instead.

Tags: geometry, circles

I have 2 points that form a line, along with a center point for a circle and its radius.
The formula for my circle is:

> $(x - C_x)^2 + (y - C_y)^2 = r^2
> ,$ where $C$ denotes CircleCenter

The formula for my line (since it's 2 points) is:

> $(y - y_1) = m (x-x_1),$ where $m = y_2/y_1 - x_2/x_1$
>
> $y = m(x-x_1) + y_1$

I substituted the formula so that all of them are variables of $x$ (substitute formula 2 in 1), then I calculated both values of $x,$ which I then reused in the original formula to calculate the corresponding $y$ values:

> $y = m(x - x_1) + y_1,$ where $x$ is the 2 values

The output I'm getting, however, is an projection rather than an intersection, such as the points of intersection are ALWAYS counted even though the points are outside/inside the circle.

Provided pictures with examples.

[Correct Intersection Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYhF2.png)

[Incorrect Intersection Picture #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxrVT.png)

[Incorrect Intersection Picture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpNd1.png)

Edit: I've been asked to post the formulas that I substituted:

> $x^2 - 2xC_x + C_x^2 + (m(x-x_1) + y_1)^2 - 2(m(x-x_1) + y_1) C_y + C_y^2 - r^2 = 0$

Comment: @dxiv I added that into the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting "projected" points of intersection because

$$ y = m(x - x_1) + y_1 $$

is the formula of a *line.*
You can increase or decrease $x$ indefinitely and find values of $y$
for every value of $x,$ not just the values of $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2.$

If you want to find intersections *only with the segment,*
you can do it in two steps. First, find all intersections with the line.
Then discard any intersection whose $x$ coordinate is not between $x_1$ and $x_2.$

---

Incidentally, in computing the equation of your line,
$m \neq y_2/y_1 - x_2/x_1.$
The correct formula is $$m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}.$$

Comment: Thank you it worked just fine! And for the slope, yes it's a typo. Thanks!